# Switching to Real mode(16 bit) using assembly language

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, 16-bit

I am actually trying to make a digital clock in assembly language that will also have some graphics(drawn lines). So in need to use interupt commands and for that I have to access real mode using assembly language in MASM. Please help if you know how?

Comment: Switching to real mode from where?

Comment: If I use .model small it gives error

Comment: @Ped7g switching the mode as our PCs use protected mode so we need to switch to real mode

Comment: why is your PC using protected mode?

Comment: You cannot really switch to real mode under modern operating systems. Consider running your program in dosbox or similar.

Comment: Or use whatever graphics services your environment offers.

Comment: What fuz and Jester said... plus even if you would manage to switch to real mode under modern OS, and draw lines to screen by BIOS calls, you would have either stay in real mode (OS not functioning any more), or after returning to OS it's quite likely it would overdraw your graphics soon, as it would be not aware of it's presence on screen (and actually it's very unlikely your BIOS does support the graphics mode used by the OS in protected mode, BIOS real mode gfx support didn't follow the development of modern gfx drivers, so it's still at VESA2.0 level at most AFAIK, often only VESA1 mess).

Comment: But when you use interrupt commands or try to manipulate graphics using assembly language, you have to use 16 bit mode, that is real mode

Comment: Well, you can't use `int 10h` in modern OS. It will not work (even if you would find some exploit, how to switch back to real mode). In linux you can use for example SDL library, which has IMHO reasonably simple API to call even from assembly (of course you can use even the native OS API, but I'm not sure how much easy is that one, considering the X vs wayland vs DRM/randr, etc.. I didn't really ever studied that, I was using usually some kind of framework between me and X11/wayland).  If you insist on using `int 10h`, create DOS exe and run it under dosbox, dosbox has `int 10h` emulation.

Comment: @Ped7g so what should I do to display a clock using assembly language that should have some graphics like lines drawn to show the time?

Comment: @SalarAhmad Use the OS API. From the tags, I deduce the OS is Windows, so I advise the use of GDI. You can Google for many examples. If you don't feel confident with assembly, do it in C first.